# Dymanically Update Data in Highchart: Load Event is not Working

Tags: jquery, html, highcharts

Here's the scenario:

I want to update my chart by reading from a file called "data.txt". This file contains data in following format: "0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7". I can manually update my chart by placing the button and pressing it and this works perfectly fine. But when I use "load" event in my code, the web page does not display anything. It becomes blank.

Any help regarding this problem would be appreciated!

Here's my current code (with load event):

```
$(function() {
  alert(0);
  $(document).ready(function() {
    Highcharts.setOptions({
        global: {
            useUTC: false
        }
    });

    var chart;
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'spline',
            animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
            marginRight: 10,
            events: {
                load: function() {

                // set up the updating of the chart each second
                        var series = this.series[0];
                        setInterval(function() {
            $.get('data.txt', function(data) { 
                <!--alert(1);-->
                var yaxis = data.split(" ");
                var y = parseInt(yaxis[7]);     
                <!--alert(2);-->
                        var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                        series.addPoint([x, y], true, true); 
            });
                    }, 5000);
                }
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Live random data'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            tickPixelInterval: 150
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Value'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                    Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) +'<br/>'+
                    Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'My data',
            data: {}
        }]
    });
  });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
          <script src="highcharts/js/highcharts.js"></script>
          <script src="highcharts/js/modules/exporting.js"></script>

          <div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: did you try putting commas between your data points to see if that would work?

Comment: Is your `$.get` working? Alerts are showing up when uncommented? Any errors in console? After `var x = ...`  remove extra `,` and put `;`.

Comment: OK, I did what u said. $.get is working; alerts are popping up; and graph title and axes are there but the graph shows a dull black line at 7. The console gives me 2 errors:
    [17:11:05.796] TypeError: n.push is not a function @ http://127.0.0.1/highcharts/js/highcharts.js:214

--
    [17:59:04.472] TypeError: j is undefined @ http://127.0.0.1/highcharts/js/highcharts.js:220

Any idea why????  @PawełFus

Comment: @PawełFus 
When I remove all the alerts, the above errors are removed and now I get a css error:
**[18:03:57.992] Unknown property 'box-sizing'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://127.0.0.1/t.html**

Comment: _@PawełFus_ Now when I am changing my data after every 5 secs, nothing appears on the graph except for the axes and the title. Again I am getting these errors:  **[18:26:55.981] TypeError: n.push is not a function @ http://localhost/highcharts/js/highcharts.js:214** and **[18:24:40.866] Unknown property 'box-sizing'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://localhost/t.html**

Answer (score 1):

data in series should be an array:

```
series: [{
        name: 'My data',
        data: [] // <--- here
    }]
```

Comment: So, **TypeError** got removed but still getting **Unknown property 'box-sizing'. Declaration dropped. @ localhost/t.html** and **GET http://localhost/data.txt [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 1ms]** errors. Graph is not plotted. :(

Comment: Sorry, 304 is not an error, my file isnt changing but still graph cant seem to plot.

Comment: Remove from `addPoint()` extra parameters `true` and will work: http://jsfiddle.net/3bQne/94/